# Ignoring &(ampersand) in Display math mode

Tags: math-mode

I frequently go back and forth between `align` environment and display math mode

(e.g., `\[ 1+1=2\]`   vs.   `\begin{align} 1+1&=2 \end{align}`)

But one annoying thing is that I should remove `&` when I use display math mode.

I never use `&` for other purposes in display math mode, so I think a simple solution is just to ignore it in every display math mode. Any way I can achieve this?

Comment: there is no really robust way to do this, probably possible if you make & globaly active and arrange it to have different definitions but it will make your math fragments incompatible with every other latex document so I'd strongly recommend that you don't do this.

Comment: note if you define & to do nothing in `\[` and `\begin{equation}` you will have to redefine `array`, `pmatrix`, `aligned` and all similar environments to restore the normal `&`  so that you can separate array cells.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I see your points. But I have a strong feeling that there is a solution. For example, it just came to my mind that we could just redefine `\[#1\]` to `\begin{align*}#1\end{align*}`. Is this a good idea?

Comment: @user182849 No, it isn't.

Comment: No it will make much worse output, you should never use `align` for single line displays You lose the finer points of spacing such  as `\aboveshortdisplayskip` as alignments always count as full width.

Comment: you've made me agree with @egreg, that's spoiled my evening.

Comment: Thanks always for your help both David and egreg!